# Mock sqlalchemy query based on the arguments .E.g: db.session.query(Model.id)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mocking, flask-sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I sqlalchemy app with models

```py
## example file  
## models.py -- path : app/models.py
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class User(db.Model):
  
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Book'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    owned_by = = db.Column(BigInt, db.ForeignKey('User.id'))


## i want to mock `user` and `book` returns by query
def check_user_own_book(user_id):
    user = db.query.session(
            User.id,
            User.username,
    ).filter(
            User.id == user_id
    ).one_or_none()
    ## more logic. abc 

    book = db.query.session(
            Book.id,
            Book.name,
    ).filter(
            owned_by == user.id
    ).one_or_none()

     ## more logic
```

This is my test

```py
from unittest import MagicMock, mock
def test_mock_session_query(fixture_user, fixture_book, session ):
    # fixture_user , fixture_book are fixture object 
    # session is inited in confest.py
    with mock.patch('flask_sqlalchemy._QueryProperty.__get__') as mock_model:
        mock_model.filter.return_value.one_or_none.return_value = fixture_user 


        ## let test 


        # query_user_with_session return None (which is true because there is no such user with id == 1000) 
        # -> Why do mock_model does not work and how to mock this `session.query` (1)
        query_user_with_session = session.query(User.id, User.username).filter(User.id==1000).one_or_none() 
         

        # query_user_with_class returns fixture_user correctly with what we mocked
        query_user_with_class =  User.query.filter(User.id==1).one_or_none() 
        # query_book_with_class returns fixture_user (2)
        query_user_with_session = Book.query.filter(Book.id=10000).one_or_none()
        

        has_own_book = check_user_own_book(user_id=1) # this will fail because all query with one_or_none will return fixture_user
```

I have researched days for this but still dot not any answer for :

1. `Model.query` and `session.query(Model)` behave differently. So what is the technique to mock the later one
2. How to mock `return_value` of `session.query(Model.column1, Model.columns2)` based on the argument . E.g: `session.query(Model.column1, Model.columns2)` and `session.query(Model_2.column1, Model_2.columns2)` should have return different

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that mocking `session.query()` is good idea. For what is it? You can mock the query result(`Result.one_or_none()`) right away. Also I can recommend to use [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide). It's really easy, understandable and useful. Here is an example:

```
# somewhere in your code
def get_user_and_book():
    user = db.session.query(...).filter(...).one_or_none()
    book = db.session.query(...).filter(...).one_or_none()
    return user, book

# test
class Example(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one_or_none(self):
        with mock.patch('sqlalchemy.engine.result.Result.one_or_none', side_effect=(1, 2, 3, 4,)):
            # get_user_and_book() calls one_or_none() 2 times
            # so we'll expects 1, 2 - see side_effect
            a, b = get_user_and_book()
            self.assertEqual(1, a)
            self.assertEqual(2, b)
            # let's try one more time
            c, d = get_user_and_book()
            self.assertEqual(3, c)
            self.assertEqual(4, d)
```

This way you can write tests for all possible combinations(user found + book not found, user found + book found etc)